# Change fetch to async syntax

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

How can I change the following code to async syntax?

```
componentWillMount(){
 fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/homes')
          .then( response => {
              if(response.ok) {
                  return response.json();
              }
              throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');    
          })
          .then( data => {
              this.setState({
                  originalList:data,
                  displayedList: data
              });
          }
        )
          .catch( error => {
              console.error(`fetch operation failed: ${error.message}`);
          });
}
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/homes');
  const json = await res.json;
              this.setState({
                  originalList:json,
                  displayedList: json
              });
}
```

and I get the following error: Syntax error: C:/Users/EYAL/web/fe/react/airbnb/src/Homes/index.js: await is a reserved word (17:14)

Comment: await res.json()? or maybe res.json() does not return promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the `componentWillMount` method as `async` in order to use `await`. You can do that by changing the signature:

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/homes');
  const json = await res.json();
  this.setState({
    originalList: json,
    displayedList: json
  });
}
```

Also `.json` is a method so it should be `res.json()`. (Thanks [bennygenel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2315280/bennygenel))

Comment: `.json` is a method so it should be `res.json()`. Maybe you should add that as well